# Return to previous Loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

How I'll return on the other loop?

```
 for (int index = MIN_DIAGNOSIS; index <= MAX_DIAGNOSIS; index++) 
   {
       foreach (RepeaterItem ri1 in GeneralRepeater.Items)
       {
           int iItemIndex = ri1.ItemIndex;
           var myDDL = GeneralRepeater.Items[iItemIndex].FindControl("derp");
           MyPoc.Diagnoses.Diagnoses[index] = new PatientDiagnosis(/*snip*/);
           return index; 
           //error 'PatientPlanOfCare.cmdSave_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' 
           //returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by 
           //an object expression
      }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. What do you want to do?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're after. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `break;` statement in the inner loop will cause it to break out and go back to the outer loop iteration.

Comment: Yep, your code makes no sense.  You should create a very simple example that illustrates your problem and paste that in, rather than your actual code.  Also, if it fits within your question without scroll bars you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Why don't you rephrase your question in terms of what you want your code to achieve, rather than asking implementation questions. It seems like there is some confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break the inner loop and use the variable you want on the main loop.

```
for (int index = PocDiagnoses.MIN_DIAGNOSIS; index <= PocDiagnoses.MAX_DIAGNOSIS; index++) 
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri1 in GeneralRepeater.Items)
    {
        int iItemIndex = ri1.ItemIndex;
        DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)GeneralRepeater.Items[iItemIndex].FindControl("GeneralDDL");
        MyPoc.Diagnoses.Diagnoses[index] = new PatientDiagnosis(myDDL.SelectedValue, new SynergyOnSetDate(new System.DateTime(Year, Month, Day)), "01/02/2011");
        break;
    }

    // Check the index variable here.
}
```

Comment: Not much point using the inner loop if you break after the first iteration without a conditional...

Answer (score -2):

Like what was commented, its hard to tell what you are trying to do.
According to the error message in your comments, this code is executing in a method that returns void, meaning your `return` statement should not have `index` after it.